# How to intelligently/better filter ArrayList?

Tags: java

For example, I have a `ArrayList` of `RegisteredUser`. The future admin, want to have a filter in the system. If admin set to user searching filter, for example  `age < 30`, the program should return the all registered users who are under 30 years old. Of course admin can add more than 1,2,3,4... filters

At the moment, I use an `ArrayList` as a database.

What algorithm can work best here?

```
private static ArrayList<RegisteredUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

public class RegisteredUser{
    private lõng ID;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList.stream().filter(predicate)`.

Comment: not sure if the primitive `lõng` exists ;)

Comment: @Lino is that a long long? Ofc, there's nothing to stop you [using that as a class name](https://ideone.com/JsqSbB).

Comment: Why do you mention future filters may be added? There's no way to add them now without knowing what they should do

Comment: It's a french long, also known as a baguette

Comment: @JoakimDanielson French does not feature macrons. Oh wait.

Comment: It doesn't look like it on my screen, but it's a [tilde](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F5).

Comment: @AndyTurner Glad java supports that, this allows me to name all my classes [W͎͚̝͔̭̮ì͕͇̯̯̱t͎̰̻ͅh͍̟̗ ̟͙̣̪̩t̖̹̮̹̠̞͖h͙̻̘̖͙͕i̝̹̮͕̮͔͞s͎̹̥͓ ̺̪͖͟f̞̞̼͕͈̳̀o̬̜̺̱ṇ̼̜͕͜ͅt](https://eeemo.net/).

Comment: Back on topic... How do you represent filters? How do you plan to let the admin pick one or more of those?

Comment: @AndyTurner if it's a tilde, desperately trying to [insert comeback joke here] involving Chirac, 2003 and The Sun.

Comment: `At the moment, I use an ArrayList as a database.` Are you sure that's the best idea, arraylists aren't permanent storage. Are you writing it to a file and reading into the list each time? It sounds like you would be better off using an actual database and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example on how to apply a list of filters to a collection:

```
public List<String> applyFiltersToACollection(List<String> collection, List<Predicate<String>> filters) {
        return collection
                .stream()
                .filter(filters.stream().reduce(x->true, Predicate::and))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And an example on how to invoke this method:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Peter", "Paul", "Laura");
List<Predicate<String>> filters = Arrays.asList(name -> name.startsWith("P"), name -> name.length() >= 5);
System.out.println(applyFiltersToACollection(names, filters));
```

Hope this helps.